# Why is the selected state of my UIButton not triggered before I release my finger?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, selected

I'm trying to create a button that switches from its `normal` state to a `selected` state upon simply touching it, and the other way around. However, I didn't manage to make it work. Here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton new];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"touch_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"touch_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(138.5, 208.5, 63, 63);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(touch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)touch:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Touch");

    UIButton *button = sender;

    if (button.selected)
        button.selected = NO;
    else
        button.selected = YES;
}

@end
```

When I tap and hold, the `touch` method is triggered, as expected. However, the image of the button only changes to `touch_selected.png` after I release my finger. Any idea what could be the issue?

**Edit**: I know what `UIControlStateHighlighted` is and it's not what I'm looking for, because I want my button to change to the `selected` state after I touched it (but while I'm still holding my finger on it), and it should stay in the `selected` state after I removed my finger from the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to change the image for the highlighted state.

You shouldn't need to do anything in the `touch:` method.

Just change the line:

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"touch_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

for:

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"touch_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Then the image should change when the button is touched.

EDIT:

To have the button keep the image once the touch has been released, you essentially want to invert the selected state each time a touch is released on the button.
I suggest adding a target to the button:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPushed) forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then in that method, invert the selected state:

```
- (void)buttonPushed
{
    [myButton setSelected:!myButton.selected];
}
```

That should hopefully do the trick!

Comment: This is actually what I'm doing right now. :) (except I'm using an `if`-statement in the `buttonPushed` method, as it's a school project and it makes it a bit more readable)

Answer (score 3):

For what you are trying to achieve, you should be using:  `UIControlStateHighlighted` not `UIControlStateSelected`

Selected is when the user is finished interacting with it, while highlighted is for when the user is currently interacting with it. I think you've mis interpreted the Ui control state flow.

**EDIT:**
You seem to be confused about the underlying logic thats playing here. Let me try to explain.

There are 3 states:

- A - UnSelected
- B - Highlighted
- C - Selected

What you have done is told your control to use specific images for states A and C, then told it not to react as it normally would in state B. Then you have told it, while in state B transition to state C.

This is all conflicting with the underlying logic inside the button. you can't do this.

You need to specify images for state A and B, and if you need it to be selected after this you need to do so after you release your finger. The internal logic will switch its states after you release your finger as its no longer in the state it was in and it needs to remove the state of highlighted. Its ignoring the fact that you have set it to selected.

If this doesn't suit you, you will need to create your own button

Comment: Before I added that line of code, the button showed a highlighted state, which I didn't want. Hence, I added this line to prevent that.

Comment: @timvermeulen ok, the rest of my point still stands however, I will edit and remove that

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting my intentions. I want my button to change to the selected change after I touched it (so it should change while I'm still holding it), and it should stay in that selected state after I released my finger.

Comment: @timvermeulen yes im aware of what you are trying to do. The last line  of your question says the image is only changed when you release your finger. Leave everything the way it is and change the "selected" image control state to `UIControlStateHighlighted` , you are expecting the button to simple go from unselected to selected. There is an intermediate state of highlighted. You will need to override this functionality by doing the above

Comment: But then the button goes back to the `normal` state after I release my finger.

Comment: @timvermeulen ok that you didn't specify in the question, I was assuming that was working. I've edited my answer

Comment: That clears things up a bit, thanks. Do you have any idea how I could accomplish what I've been trying to do?

Comment: @timvermeulen I would set the images as `UIControlStateNormal` and `UIControlStateHighlighted` and change your trigger to `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` that way the image will change when your finger touches it and it will be in selected state after this, so any code running after the button press will see it as selected

Comment: @timvermeulen no problem, enjoy

Comment: Found this discussion because I am equally confused as timvermeulen about behaviour of UIButton. I also managed to get working what I wanted, but only by setting images for the various states. However, in IB you can set different Titles for states Default, Highlighted, Selected and Disabled. I have never seen the Title for "Selected" appear. When is that shown?

Answer (score 0):

Because you ask to do so. You are changing image when button is selected. If you want to change image when user touch then set an image for `UIControlStateHighlighted` it will change image when `button` will be in `highlighted` state.

Comment: But when I touch the button, the `touch:` method is triggered (which I verified with the `NSLog`) which changes the `selected` property of my button.

Comment: But that is not selected state, that is highlighted state... your set selected but it will take effect when you release it... if you tap and keep hold it, its highlighted state...

Answer (score 0):

The `UIControlStateSelected` does not mean what you think it means. A control is selected when it is tapped on. When you tap and hold the control, then drag away from that control, it isn't selected. You are looking for `UIControlStateHighlighted`. Setting the `selected` property yourself is unnecessary, too. `UIButton` will take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

The button also has a `highlighted` state which (visually) overrides the `selected` state. The highlighted state is maintained internally to show touches.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Any idea how I can fix that? (or shouldn't I?)